# Force C++ to use function from local header

Tags: c++, include

I have code that looks like this:

```
#include <A.h>
#include "B.h"
[...]
foo();
```

A and B contain the same function foo. How can I force C++ to use foo() from B?

Comment: Put it in a namespace. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include `B.h` from within a `namespace`, like so:

```
namespace local {
#include "B.h"
}
```

`local::foo()` will then refer to the declaration from `B.h`

Now if you're in control of the contents of `B.h`, I would advise you to define the namespace within `B.h` (or change the name of your functions to avoid conflicts).

Comment: Good answer! What if B.h contains another namespace "ns" that needs to be accessed: local::ns::foo? (error: "Local::ns has not been declared")

Comment: Well in that case `ns::foo` is already distinguishable from the other `foo` and there is no point in adding another namespace on top of it. Now if you don't know what lies inside your own includes, accessing `foo` will only be one of your many concerns ;)

Comment: In general, you're right. However, in this case, the header A.h uses the same namespace as B.h. Btw, A and B are two headers that I don't have access to. They come from a library in two different versions.

Comment: Ah OK, but then it's just as if both functions were named `ns::foo` and we're back to square one with a slightly longer ambiguous name :).